# Cannot get angular $http to work

Tags: java, angularjs, servlets

I'm trying to get a simple angularjs login screen to work.
The angular app sends the login details via http get method to a java servlet and anticipates a json response with success/fail. The java servlet is running on Tomcat 8.0.

Unfortunately, the angular app doesn't seem to be able to receive data from the servlet (it does send the data to the servlet) - the errorCallback method of "then" is called everytime.

Also, accessing the servlet's url directly from the browser works fine (the browser shows the response string).

Can you help me to find the problem?

This is the div element in the html page:

```
        <div ng-controller = "loginCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model = "userName" placeholder="Username"></input><br>
    <input type = "text" ng-model = "userPass" placeholder="Password"></input><br>
    <button type = "button" ng-click = "login()">Login</button><br>

    {{message}}
</div>
```

This is the js code:

```
var expenseApp = angular.module("expenseApp",[]);

expenseApp.controller('loginCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.userName = "";
    $scope.userPass = "";
    $scope.message = "type in your credentials";
    $scope.login = function() {
        var address = "http://localhost:8080/ExpenseSystemServer/LoginServlet?userName=" + $scope.userName + "&userPass=" + $scope.userPass;
        $http({method:'get',
        url:address})
        .then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.message = "http success";
                },
                function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.message = "http error";
                });
    };  
}]);
```

And this is the servlet doGet method in java (the servlet's class name is LoginServlet):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        String userPass = request.getParameter("userPass");
        System.out.print("Login attempt with " + userName + "; " + userPass + ": ");
        if (userName == null || userPass == null || !userName.equals("admin") || !userPass.equals("pass")){
            response.getWriter().write("{'success':false,'message':'wrong details'}");
            System.out.println("failed.");
        }
        else {
            response.getWriter().write("{'success':true, 'user':{'name':'admin'},'message':'Hi admin!'}");
            System.out.println("succeeded.");
        }

    }
```

Can you help me here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're sending invalid JSON from the servlet. JSON keys and string values must be in double quotes, not single quotes. Use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON. Or better, create a Java object, and a marshaller like Jackson to transform the object to valid JSON.

Also, instead of sending back a successful response (with code 200), with an object property "success" set to false, you should return an error response (400 if the required credentials are not there at all, 401 if they're not valid). Doing that not only shows respect for the HTTP protocol, but allows using http promises as intended:

```
http(...).then(successCallback, errorCallback)
```

instead of

```
http(...).then(successButActuallyMaybeErrorCallback, anotherErrorCallback)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid using single quotes that should be double

It's a really bad practice to create your own when most languages can encode it for you from native arrays and objects. I don't know best way using java but it needs to look like:

```
response.getWriter().write('{"success":false,"message":"wrong details"}');
```

note switch of single and double quotes